# Retrieving Autogenerated content in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

Well, here's my problem.  I've got a php script which posts a message to a mysql database.  The mysql database generates two values automatically, one is a timestamp and the other one is a unique id for the message.

I need those values to be able to update my page using ajax (json).  I want to know how do I get those values from the same php script from where i've posted my message to be stored in the mysql database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) will give you the last autoincrement value.  Then you can use a `SELECT` to retrieve the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to retrieve last inserted ID from the table